# Spacemacs kept repositioning the cursor when there's unmatched parenthesis

Tags: spacemacs, motion

I'm new to Emacs, and there's one thing I don't understand. Suppose there's a file called `test.el`, which have the following contents:

```
(setq
```

Yes, the parenthesis is not closed, because I haven't finished this file. But when I positioned my cursor just after `setq` and typed a `SPC` to continue to write the code, the cursor moved back to the beginning of the line. Why? How can I prevent it from repositioning the cursor, it's annoying.

This problem only occurs with Spacemacs and lisp code, I didn't found the problem with the vanilla Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of checking and searching, I find the following auto save command to be the culprit.

```
(run-with-timer 3 3 (lambda () (save-some-buffers t)))
```

It saves the current buffer every 3 seconds, and it seems that Emacs repositions the current elisp file after saving. Removing this line works.